# Software for writing stories

Tags: text-editor, plain-text

I'm looking for software on Windows, where I can write stories. 
So I can organize things easy. When I type something like `#girl1` that I can later edit it to a name. And that I don't need to find every `#girl1` and replace that word myself. And that I can make notes easily.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47964/how-to-write-a-book-in-latex

Comment: What operating system? What budget?

Comment: The only problem is that you need to remember who #girl1 was. In that case is the exact same feature that using Word to replace #girl1 to an actual name.

Answer (score 2):

Scrivener is one of the best known pieces of software created specifically with writers in mind. It is not free (40 USD at time of writing, though they do promotions). You do get a free trial though.

https://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php

Comment: Scrivener is good software.

Comment: Please post a screenshot showing the #girl1 functionality in action.

Answer (score 2):

Word does have a lot of functionalities like the one you are talking about. On the '**home**' tab, there is a tool '**replacement**' (I bet, I don't have the english version sorry) on the left, where you can choose the word you want to change, and it'll change it in all your document!

Plus, for the organised side, I must say Word also has quite a headstart with its '**Titles**' (on 'home' tab too)...

You also have the possibility to make comments all over your stories, in case you forgot to say something and want to add it later on (in the '**references**' tab).

To be honest, Word is quite an editor but sadly its main and more useful fonctions are way too unknown. Take a day to really find out how it works, and what you can do with it, it's amazing!

(P.S: no I do not own Microsoft nor have been paid for saying this, I wish though...)

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to **CudaText** editor with syntax (lexer) **Fountain**. But it works not like this: you cannot rename some name, but must write all names correctly. Fountain syntax is very good for writings, see [Fountain page](https://fountain.io/syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You could try True Novelist. It is a web-based text editor stripped down to the very text and easy to use as such. Also it has chapter organization.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing "#girl1" with a name is a simple matter of *find and replace*; virtually any editor will do this. As for easily taking notes, several apps come to mind and, since I don't know you're budget, your OS, or the length of what you're wanting to write, I'll err on the side of cheap, cross-platform, and varied:

1. [Manuskript](https://www.theologeek.ch/manuskript/)

   - Free
   - Can associate & manage notes, metadata, character sketches, etc., with project.
   - Intended for writing novels.
2. [Joplin](https://joplin.cozic.net)

   - Free
   - Store files in notebooks
   - Tag files for reference
   - Use the built-in editor or configure the external editor of your choice in settings.
   - Sync enabled
   - Marketed for notes but also works as a project manager
3. [WriteMonkey](https://writemonkey.com/)

   - Freemium
   - From the website:

> REPOSITORY (unique feature)
>   Document based repository mode. Store your notes, unfinished parts, data clippings or URL's into the same text file. Simply toggle between main text and repository by pressing ALT + R.
>
> AS YOU TYPE REPLACEMENTS
>   Define short trigger strings that will be automatically replaced by corresponding target strings such as special characters, signatures, addresses, date-time stamps etc.